# Regex capitalize second letter of word

Tags: php, regex

Using php, i would like to take an all lowercase word and if the first letter of the word starts with an `i` then capitalise the second letter.

So if my word was `iphone` then after the `preg_replace()` the string would be `iPhone`.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) And why do you specifically need your solution to be regex-based?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/^i([a-z])([a-z]+)$/e', '"i" . strtoupper("\\1") . "\\2"', $str);
```

This code checks a single word to see if it is all lowercase.  If so it capitalizes the second letter.

If it gets more complex, you may want to use [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) instead.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `(?<=\b\w)(\w)` for find letter but regex can't modify string, use regex match's index for capitalize by php